# Can multiple base classes have the same virtual method?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

1. class A has a pure virtual method `read()`
2. class B has an implemented virtual method `read()`
3. I have a class C that inherits A and B
4. Can this happen?

What I'm trying to achieve is that the two base classes A and B complement each other.

So C `read()` method would actually call class B `read()`

```cpp
class A {
    virtual int get_data() = 0;

    void print() {
        log(get_data());
    }
}

class B {
    virtual int get_data() {
        return 4;
    }
}

class C : public A, public B {

}
```

```
C my_class;
my_class.print(); // should log 4;
```

I'm not on my computer nor will have opportunity in the next couple of weeks so I can't test this... but I'm designing the architecture and needed to know if this is possible and if not.. how can this be accomplished!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but there are many online compilers you can use to check things like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ (I'm not saying you're wrong for asking, just mentioning)

Comment: well it doesn't compile in the online compiler you posted.. if this is not allowed then how can I do something like this?

Comment: @xDGameStudios when something doesn't compile, you should read the error message.

Comment: @eerorika I read the error message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can multiple base classes have the same virtual method?
>
> 4. Can this happen?

Yes.

> So C read() method would actually call class B read()

That doesn't happen automatically. A member function of base doesn't override a function of an unrelated base.

You can add an override to `C`:

```
class C : public A, public B {
    int get_data() override;
}
```

This overrides *both* `A::get_data` and `B::get_data`. In order to *"actually call class B read()"*, you can indeed make such call:

```
int C::get_data() {
    return B::get_data();
}
```

Or... that would be possible if you hadn't declared `B::get_data` private.

---

Overriding a function in another base without explicitly delegating in derived *is* possible if you change your hierarchy a bit. In particular, you need a common base, and virtual inheritance:

```
struct Base {
    virtual int get_data() = 0;
};

struct A : virtual Base {
    void print() {
        std::cout << get_data();
    }
};

struct B : virtual Base {
    int get_data() override {
        return 4;
    }
};

struct C : A, B {};
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know two classes of the same base could converge into a third class!