# Overriding function with another parent class functions

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a C++ header-only wrapper for Expat and I try to separate callbacks from the parser while having the parser implementing theses callbacks.

```cpp
class Callbacks { inline virtual XHandler(Parser &parser) { /* Do nothing by default */ }; };
class Main: public Callbacks {
    XML_Parser parser;
    inline void set_parser(XML_Parser new_parser) {
        parser = new_parser;
        XML_SetUserData(new_parser,this);
        XML_SetXHandler(parser,
            [] (void *userData) {
                Parser &parser = *static_cast<Parser*>(userData);
                return parser.XHandler(parser);
            });
    };
};
```

I want to create a subclass pair with special `Callbacks` and a `Parser` that implement them :

```cpp
class SubCallbacks override { inline XHandler(Parser &parser) {/* Something */};};
class SubParser: public Parser, public SubCallbacks {}; // <-- Yeah it's really empty !
```

When the lambda callback get called on a `SubParser`, gdb say that `parser` have the `_vptr` of `SubParser`, but it's the `Parser`'s virtual function that get called instead of the `SubCallbacks` one.

I'm a beginner in C++, and I'm may be doing something odd. But **how can I override `Callbacks` functions with implementation of the parent `SubCallbacks` class ?**

Here's an example (GCC 10.1.0) that reproduce the current behavior :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
    // C minimal callback caller code (mimic Expat callbacks)
    typedef void(*Callback)(void*);
    typedef struct {void* data; Callback callback;} Opaque;
    Opaque *opaque_new()
    {
        return (Opaque*)malloc(sizeof(Opaque));
    }
    void opaque_set_callback(Opaque *opaq, Callback callback)
    {
        opaq->callback = callback;
    }
    void opaque_set_data(Opaque *opaq, void* data)
    {
        opaq->data = data;
    }
    void opaque_do_work(Opaque *opaq)
    {
        opaq->callback(opaq->data);
    }
};

// The class holder
class Main;
// Callbacks are separated
class Callbacks {
    public:
        virtual inline void Hey(Main& main) {/* By default do nothing */};
};

class Main: protected Callbacks {
    private:
        Opaque *opaque;
        // ↓ Dedicated function because there's multiple constructors in full code ↓
        inline void set_opaque(Opaque *new_opaque) { 
            opaque = new_opaque;
            opaque_set_data(opaque,this);
            opaque_set_callback(opaque,
                [] (void *userData) {
                    Main &main = *static_cast<Main*>(userData);
                    return main.Hey(main);
                }
            );
        }
    public:
        inline Main() {
            set_opaque(opaque_new());
        };
        inline void DoWork() {
            opaque_do_work(opaque);
        };
};
class SubCallbacks: protected Callbacks {
    public:
        inline void Hey(Main& main) override {std::cout << "Hey!" << std::endl;};
};
class SubMain: public Main, public SubCallbacks {
    // I expect SubCallbacks to override Main Callbacks functions
};

int main()
{
    SubMain().DoWork();
}
```

Comment: Not quite your problem, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445840/can-multiple-base-classes-have-the-same-virtual-method) has the solution you need - `SubMain` needs to override `Hey` and pass the call to `SubCallbacks::Hey`. Also note that you have two `Callbacks` objects (one in `Main` and one in `SubCallbacks`.

Comment: Oh ! You are right @1201ProgramAlarm. I let you answer my question, if you want.